# Blinking LED on ATMEGA168. Error rc=-1. AVRDUDE

Tags: avr

I apologise in advance. This is my first project. I keep getting this error

```
avrdude: error: programm enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
     Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
     this check.
```

when i enter the command

```
 avrdude -p m168p -c usbasp
```

This has something to do with how I have connected the 6-pin to the AVR.
I have included pictures but I have tried and tried again to no avail! has anyone got any suggestions?

I am using a USBasp. There is a red light on my USbasp when i plug it in. Should it be green? I do not know.

[image]

This is my breadboard.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where did the chip come from?

Comment: Check all the connections, check the voltage across the VCC and GND pins on the Atmega.

Comment: The chip came from Ebay. Could it be a fake ? I would need a voltmeter. I shall order one, it will be useful for future projects anyway!

Comment: @HMPARTICLE Do you know if it has the internal fuses set for the internal clock (or is preloaded for arduino or something....in which case it is looking for an external clock)

Comment: My voltmeter has arrived and I am getting a reading of 0.06 when on 2V.

Comment: No, I do not think so, so i am guessing it has fuses set for internal clock.

Comment: Where is your pull up resistor on the reset pin?

Comment: Reading of 0.06 where? Did you put your voltmeter on AC or DC mode?

Comment: I think it is in DC mode. The V with the straight line measures DC?

Comment: Indeed. But what pins did you measure across? I have a hard time believing that the blue LED would be on if the supply was only 0.06V.

Comment: I removed the chip from the breadboard and measured across the VCC and GND pins. The voltage reading did not remain at 0.06V, but for the most part it was.

Comment: Do you think it could be that the USBasp is faulty? I mean, everything is connected as per in the diagram given to me in the book. I have one of these [link](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/131839253890?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) but I can not find any documentation on the pins.

Answer (score 4):

In your diagram you have pin 7 and 8 connected to VCC and GND respectively.

You are missing connections pin 20 and 22 for AVCC and GND respectively.

The way chips are powered internally is a crapshoot. Everything depends on how the internal die is set up and how power is actually routed. Even though these seem like "analog only" connections they **do** need powered and a decoupling capacitor even if not using the A to D converter.

When the programmer talks to the chip it pulls and holds the reset line low and sends programming instructions. If the chip does not reply you get rc=-1 error.

The two main causes of the chip not replying is wiring or oscillator problems. I'm assuming that you have a virgin chip and it is set to the internal oscillator.

As far as the wiring goes all VCC and GND connections need made and decoupling capacitors need added to all. **Note the black and two red wires on the right that your missing.**  As @Naz pointed out also add a pullup to the RESET line. Here is the [tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone) that the image came from. 
[image]

Comment: Where do I connect AVCC to on the 6 pin? Thanks for your reply, why do I need to do this? I have tried to follow multiple tutorials to achieve the same outcome (flashing LED's) and have had the same problem! I am almost convinced that I have a faulty...something :(

Comment: @HMPARTICLE I updated my answer.

Comment: All the power pins and the GNDs must be connected. That's great, I think he was missing the pull up resistor on the Reset pin

Comment: @Naz That too is important!!

Comment: I have ordered a few voltage regulators. I shall give that a go when they arrive.

Comment: You shouldn't need a reset resistor to program it.

Comment: @BWalker Arguable, if the programmer does not get the chip into programming mode on the first try the chip could be stuck in limbo until a full power cycle. This is because if the SPI bus loses synchronization there is no way to resynchronize it without pulling the reset line high and then back low again.

Comment: @vini_i as far as I'm aware, most programmers (that i've used) control the reset line on their own, driving it high or low, and so dont need a pullup resistor. Even if they didn't, adding a pull up resistor wouldn't affect anything, unless the environment was noisy.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, when I get these kind of errors, I check several things:

1. I make sure that all wiring is done precisely as it has to be. It is not rare for me to hook up RESET in a way that is doesn't make any contact.
2. I check if resistor that I used for pulling RESET up is connected to VCC. It looks like you have used yours to pull RESET low. What it means is even though you should probably be able to program it, your MCU won't start because it is in RESET state. I am pretty sure that is your mistake

Answer (score -1):

Give this site to check out your wiring. http://theamateurmaker.com/programming-atmega168-with-the-tiny-avr-programmer/  I've had a similar problem with my wiring and found this site and I found my error. Hope this helps. Also make sure the bootloader is loaded.

Comment: You may want to load/reload the Bootloader just to make sure this is one in the chip. If there isn't a Bootloader you could get the error message.

Comment: No. A bootloader is not relevant when using an ISP connection, in fact ordinary use of ISP will remove any bootloader previously present as the ISP interface on this series is only capable of doing a full erase, not a partial one.

Comment: If more program space is what your looking for buy a ATmega328. It the same chip as the ATmega168 but with twice the storage space. Also check out a question on this same site http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30908/simplest-way-to-upload-sketches-onto-hackduino-without-having-a-arduino-duemil

Comment: I hope  I don't get fined another reputation points for this comment. There are a lot of sites out there that deal with the programming of arduino boards that can apply here. Just look around and read them.

Comment: Did you get it working?  If what did it turn out to be?